# How Merge two list with old order?

Tags: java

I have two list:

```
    private static final List<String> NUMERIC_VALUES = Arrays.asList("100","5","1","0","1111111","6","11","12","50","99","101");

    private static final List<String> ALPHANUMERIC_VALUES = Arrays.asList("10A0", "1B1", "6A", "A0", "A1", "ABC", "C5", "T-1", "TT", "TTT",
                    "434/32145", "434/12354", "32654B", "32654A", "32654B/1");
```

After merge I would have:

```
[100, 5, 1, 0, 1111111, 6, 11, 12, 50, 99, 101, 10A0, 1B1, 6A, A0, A1, ABC, C5, T-1, TT, TTT, 434/32145, 434/12354, 32654B, 32654A, 32654B/1]
```

I tried:

```
List<String> result = Stream.concat(NUMERIC_VALUES.stream(), ALPHANUMERIC_VALUES.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And also:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
result.addAll(NUMERIC_VALUES);
result.addAll(ALPHANUMERIC_VALUES);
```

But always I'm getting

```
[100, 5, 1, 0, 1111111, 6, 11, 12, 50, 99, 101, 10A0, 1B1, 32654A, 32654B, 32654B/1, 434/12354, 434/32145, 6A, A0, A1, ABC, C5, T-1, TT, TTT]
```

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with the code that you posted. There may be some other problem going on.

Answer (score 0):

but this work well:

```
//to concat two list
 List<String> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

  result.forEach(s->System.out.print(s+" "));
```

Comment: indeed sorry!  but using concat im getting the result that you want!

Comment: you can check this link  <https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4da9fdb036e746b7dc19110398fd7196 ?> and you can take the code and compil it in https://www.compilejava.net/